# How to display (convert) simple Python dictionary to string for jinja2 template/ GAE

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-app-engine, dictionary

Simple question but most of the search around has not yielded a complete answer. I'm currently writing comments to the datastore (GAE) using angularjs. However my page shows the comments as dictionaries instead of strings(actual output I require). I want to be able to fetch the comments in the jinja2 template What function suits my needs. Below are my files. TIA

**PYTHON (main.py)**

```
class expHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    title="Colin_MK: Experience"
    recommendations = Recommendation.query()
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps([rec.to_dict() for rec in recommendations]))
    template_vars = {'title': title, 'recommendations': recommendations}
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/exp.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_vars))

def post(self):
    r = json.loads(self.request.body)

    new_comment = Recommendation(comment=r['comment'])
    new_comment.put()

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/bio', bioHandler),
    ('/exp', expHandler),
], debug=True)
```

**HTML (Jinja2 templating)**

```
{% extends "home.html"%}
{% block content %}


<div ng-controller="commentController" class="formcontent">
    <div class ="container">

            <form ng-submit="addComment()" method="post" id="frmComment">

                <textarea ng-model="formFields.comment" id="comment" name="commento" class="form-control status-box sameline" rows="2" placeholder="Recommend Colin"></textarea>
            </form>
            <div class="button-group pull-right sameline">
                    <p class="counter">140</p>
                    <button form ="frmComment"class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <ul class="posts">
            <li ng-repeat = "c in comments">
                    {< c.comment >}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**ANGULAR (*get part)**

```
var commentApp = angular.module('commentApp', [])

commentApp.config(['$interpolateProvider', function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{<');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('>}');
}]);

commentApp.controller('commentController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formFields = {
        comment : ""
    }

    $scope.comments = [];

    $scope.init = function(){

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/exp'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.comments = response;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

    };

    $scope.init();
```

[Required display](http://www.harrymarshall.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Screen-Shot-2015-07-22-at-14.58.15.png)

[What's currently displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiRyb.png)

Comment: Please show an example of the output you're getting, and explain how it differs from what you want.

Comment: @DanielRoseman shout out for waving back! I've attached both displays. I manage to write to the datastore but upon calling the comments back to jinja (for display), the page is broken though displaying the comments in raw dictionary form (at the top of the page - above the nav bar).

Comment: This isn't very clear unfortunately. I don't *think* that the view you've shown is rendering the template that you've shown, but I'm not certain; it seems like there is a main view which renders that template, and Angular is then making Ajax requests to that `expHandler` view. In which case, what is "exp.html"?

Comment: Sorry it's coz I did not show you the rest of the code esp communicating the end points I was working with. There is a comments handler that's actually supposed to 'json.dumps' the data to '/comments' handler then /exp handler collects the comments from /comments. Before I was doin both in one handler.The few changes I made in angular were to change the $http get url to /comments instead of /exp and viceversa for $http post. Again I was mistakenly pointing both of them to /exp hence causing the mix up! I've fixed it.The **MAIN** fix though was adding **.data** to response to fetch all objects.

Comment: Colin, do you mind adding that as an answer? Fully formulating it. Since your current question seems well documented and researched enough, it might be a good, helpful post for future users of Stack Overflow :)